# Pretty print 2D list?

Tags: python, matrix

Is there a simple, built-in way to print a 2D Python list as a 2D matrix?

So this:

```
[["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
```

would become something like

```
A    B
C    D
```

I found the `pprint` module, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: I would have called that a 3D list.  If you are willing to pull it in, `numpy` is pretty good about this sort of thing.

Comment: Actually, `print` has a pretty neat way to do things like this. There is an `end = foo` argument that allows you to customize what you put at the end of a print statement (default is `\n`). See my answer for future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73229153/13600624.

Comment: The simplest solution for this example would be just `for x in your_list: print(x)`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

To make things interesting, let's try with a bigger matrix:

```
matrix = [
   ["Ah!",  "We do have some Camembert", "sir"],
   ["It's a bit", "runny", "sir"],
   ["Well,",  "as a matter of fact it's", "very runny, sir"],
   ["I think it's runnier",  "than you",  "like it, sir"]
]

s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in matrix]
lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
print '\n'.join(table)
```

Output:

```
Ah!                     We do have some Camembert   sir            
It's a bit              runny                       sir            
Well,                   as a matter of fact it's    very runny, sir
I think it's runnier    than you                    like it, sir
```

UPD: for multiline cells, something like this should work:

```
text = [
    ["Ah!",  "We do have\nsome Camembert", "sir"],
    ["It's a bit", "runny", "sir"],
    ["Well,",  "as a matter\nof fact it's", "very runny,\nsir"],
    ["I think it's\nrunnier",  "than you",  "like it,\nsir"]
]

from itertools import chain, izip_longest

matrix = chain.from_iterable(
    izip_longest(
        *(x.splitlines() for x in y), 
        fillvalue='') 
    for y in text)
```

And then apply the above code.

See also http://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable

Comment: genius! BUT what if we want multiple lines within each cell i.e. a 3D array :)

Comment: @CpILL: one option would be to unzip 3D into a 2D: `[[[a,b,c],[xyz]]]=>[[a,x],[b,y],[c,z]]` and then apply the above.

Comment: you mean pivot the data?

Comment: @CpILL: added an example.

Comment: How could we limit the table to, say, the top 10 values?

Answer (score 70):

For Python 3 without any third part libs:

```
matrix = [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]

print('\n'.join(['\t'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in matrix]))
```

Output

```
A   B
C   D
```

Comment: underrated answer right here. Works great, keeps it native, one line FTW.

Comment: My only regret is that I have but one upvote to give for this answer

Comment: We should give a medal to this guy.

Answer (score 58):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to pretty-print a 2D matrix by converting it to a DataFrame object:

```
import pandas as pd
x = [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
print(pd.DataFrame(x))


   0  1
0  A  B
1  C  D
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

You can always use **[numpy](https://www.numpy.org/)**:

```
import numpy as np
A = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
print(np.matrix(A))
```

**Output:**

```
[['A' 'B']
 ['C' 'D']]
```

Comment: showing the output for comparison with other solutions would be a 'nice to have'

Comment: Use `print(np.array(A))` to avoid warnings

Answer (score 13):

Just to provide a simpler alternative to [`print('\n'.join(\['\t'.join(\[str(cell) for cell in row\]) for row in matrix\]))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257693/7129538) :

```
matrix = [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
for row in matrix:
    print(*row)
```

**Explanation**
`*row` unpacks `row`, so `print("A", "B")` is called when `row` is `["A", "B"]`, for example.

**Note**
Both answers will only be formatted nicely if each column has the same width. To change the  delimiter, use the `sep` keyword. For example,

```
for row in matrix:
    print(*row, sep=', ')
```

will print

```
A, B
C, D
```

instead.

**One-liner without a for loop**

```
print(*(' '.join(row) for row in matrix), sep='\n')
```

`' '.join(row) for row in matrix)` returns a string for every row, e.g. `A B` when `row` is `["A", "B"]`.

`*(' '.join(row) for row in matrix), sep='\n')` unpacks the generator returning the sequence `'A B', 'C D'`, so that `print('A B', 'C D', sep='\n')` is called for the example `matrix` given.

Comment: Good stuff, ey.

Comment: What if the items are different lengths?

Answer (score 11):

Without any third party libraries, you could do:

```
matrix = [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
print(*matrix, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B']
['C', 'D']
```

Comment: Maybe people would want something prettier than that…

Comment: Will not work if the matrix is very large, with lots of decimal points, etc. It requires advanced formatting which is missing in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

A more lightweight approach than `pandas` is to use the `prettytable` module

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]

p = PrettyTable()
for row in x:
    p.add_row(row)

print p.get_string(header=False, border=False)
```

yields:

```
A B
C D
```

`prettytable` has lots of options to format your output in different ways.

See https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/ for more info

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a Notebook/IPython environment, then sympy can print pleasing matrices using IPython.display:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix, init_printing
init_printing()

print(np.random.random((3,3)))
display(np.random.random((3,3)))
display(Matrix(np.random.random((3,3))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/), which can optionally print headers too:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

lst = [['London', 20],['Paris', 30]]
print(tabulate(lst, headers=['City', 'Temperature']))
```

:

```
City      Temperature
------  -------------
London             20
Paris              30
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is to do it using the "end" parameter in `print()`. This works only because in Python (and in many other languages), all letters are the same width.

```
table = [["A", "BC"], ["DEFG", "HIJ"]]
for row in table:
    for col in row:
        spaces = 5 #adjust as needed
        spaces -= (len(col) - 1) #spaces everything out
        print(col, end = " " * spaces)
    print() #add line break before next row
```

The "end" function sets what will be printed after the end of the arguments, as the default is `\n`.

As you can see, I offseted how many spaces there are according to the length of each item in each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can update `print`'s `end=' '` so that it prints space instead of '\n' in the inner loop and outer loop can have `print()`.

```py
a=[["a","b"],["c","d"]]
for i in a:
  for j in i:
    print(j, end=' ')
  print()
```

I found this solution from [here](https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/).

Answer (score -4):

See the following code.

```
# Define an empty list (intended to be used as a matrix)
matrix = [] 
matrix.append([1, 2, 3, 4])
matrix.append([4, 6, 7, 8])
print matrix
# Now just print out the two rows separately
print matrix[0]
print matrix[1]
```

Comment: try this and see what happens does not sound like an answer. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer