# Printing out a 2D list like a table with Python

Tags: python, list, tabular

I'm trying to print out a 2D list like a table, and I found a piece of code here:
[Pretty print 2D Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214809/pretty-print-2d-python-list)

But I couldn't understand how it really works, can anyone please explain to me?

```
s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in matrix]
lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
print '\n'.join(table)
```

Comment: What don't you understand? List comprehensions? map? zip? argument unpacking? join? format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have commented, there are a lot of concepts going on here (too many to be manageable in a single answer). But for your further study (try out each statement in turn with a (small) example 2D list), here's how it breaks down:

Turn the data into a list of lists of strings (uses *list comprehension*):

```
s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in matrix]
```

Get a list of the maximum number of characters in each column so we know how to format the columns:

```
lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
```

(This one is more complex: `zip()` here enables us to iterate over the columns of `s`, passing each to the `len()` method to find its length (this is achieved with `map()`); then find the maximum length of each column with the `max()` builtin.)

Set up the corresponding Python format strings as tab-separated entries:

```
fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
```

`fmt` is now the format specifier for every row, e.g. `'{:4}\t{:6}\t{:6}'` for three columns with widths 4,6,6 (NB only works on Python 2.7+ because the fields haven't been numbered)

Set up the table as a list of rows in their string format (use another list comprehension):

```
table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
```

Join the whole lot together in a single string, with rows separated by newlines:

```
print '\n'.join(table)
```

`join()` takes a list of strings and produces one string with them all joined together by the chosen delimiter (here, `\n`, the newline character).