# Printing all solutions in the shape of a matrix using \n\

Tags: python

This function returns all possible multiplication from 1 to d. I want to print the solution in the shape of a d×d matrix.

```
def example(d):
  for i in range(1,d+1):
      for l in range(1,d+1):
          print(i*l)
```

For `d = 5`, the expected output should look like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

Comment: Ok.. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @kkaosninja My function prints the solutions in one line but i want them to be printed in the shape of a dxd matrix. Sorry if the questions wasn't clear enough

Comment: print(i*l, end=" ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the values in your second for loop to a list, `join` the list, and finally print it.

```
def mul(d):
    for i in range(1, d+1):
        list_to_print = []
        for l in range(1, d+1):
            list_to_print.append(str(l*i))
        print(" ".join(list_to_print))

>>> mul(5)
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

If you want it to be printed in aligned rows and columns, have a read at [Pretty print 2D Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214809/pretty-print-2d-python-list).

**EDIT**

The above example will work for both Python 3 and Python 2. However, for Python 3 (as @richard has put in the comments), you can use:

```
def mul(d):
    for i in range(1, d+1):
        for l in range(1, d+1):
            print(i*l, end=" ")
        print()

>>> mul(5)
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mm = []
ll = []

def mul(d):
    for i in range(1,d+1):
        ll = []
        for l in range(1,d+1):
#             print(i*l),
            ll.append((i*l)) 
        mm.append(ll)

mul(5)

for x in mm:
   print(x)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
[4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Comment: I really need them to be printed in the shape of a dxd matrix the solutions are already fine in my function.

Comment: Well, then edit your question with the dxd output you want.

Comment: @Merlin That's something quite interesting! However, this only works for Python 2. In Python 3, it will just print it in a straight line.

Comment: @MoonCheesez okay didnt know that. Maybe i should edit that i need it for python 3.x :D