# Rotating a list of lists

Tags: python

```
m = [[5,9,1,8],
    [2,4,5,7],
    [6,3,3,2],
    [1,7,6,3]]

    rotated_map = []
    for i in range(len(m[0])):
      rotated_map.append([x[i] for x in m]) 
      print(rotated_map)

    """
    my result = [[5, 2, 6, 1], [9, 4, 3, 7], [1, 5, 3, 6], [8, 7, 2, 3]]

    desired result = [[8,7,2,3],
                      [1,5,3,6],
                      [9,4,3,7],
                      [5,2,6,1]]
    """
```

I am trying to rotate the list by putting all the last elements first from the lists into one list then the second to last element into another and so on until i get to the first element.

Comment: Also, i not even sure how to indent it to get the desired result

Answer (score 2):

[Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists) the list with `zip`, then [reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3940137/3620003) it with the `[::-1]` syntax.

```
>>> m = [[5, 9, 1, 8], [2, 4, 5, 7], [6, 3, 3, 2], [1, 7, 6, 3]]
>>> list(map(list, zip(*m)))[::-1]
>>> [[8, 7, 2, 3], [1, 5, 3, 6], [9, 4, 3, 7], [5, 2, 6, 1]]
```

edit:

If you want pretty printing, it's probably easiest to use numpy arrays all the way.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> m = [[5, 9, 1, 8], [2, 4, 5, 7], [6, 3, 3, 2], [1, 7, 6, 3]]
>>> m = np.array(m)
>>> m
>>> 
array([[5, 9, 1, 8],
       [2, 4, 5, 7],
       [6, 3, 3, 2],
       [1, 7, 6, 3]])
>>> 
>>> m.T[::-1]
>>> 
array([[8, 7, 2, 3],
       [1, 5, 3, 6],
       [9, 4, 3, 7],
       [5, 2, 6, 1]])
```

Note that `m` and `m.T[::-1]` share the same data, because `m.T[::-1]` is just another *view* of `m`. If you need to duplicate the data, use

```
result = m.T[::-1].copy()
```

Comment: hey, i havent learnt zip but do you know how to indent the lists  so it may be in columns of 4

Comment: @NaafiuMohammed you mean how to print it as a square?

Comment: @NaafiuMohammed there's a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214809/pretty-print-2d-python-list).

Answer (score 1):

You could use zip, unpacking your list of lists with the `*`, and inversing the result with `[::-1]`:

```
m = [[5,9,1,8],
    [2,4,5,7],
    [6,3,3,2],
    [1,7,6,3]]

res = [list(i) for i in zip(*m)][::-1]

>>> res
[[8, 7, 2, 3], [1, 5, 3, 6], [9, 4, 3, 7], [5, 2, 6, 1]]
```

If `numpy` is an option, transposing is easier:

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.transpose(m)[::-1]
array([[8, 7, 2, 3],
       [1, 5, 3, 6],
       [9, 4, 3, 7],
       [5, 2, 6, 1]])
# or:
>>> np.flip(np.transpose(m),0)
array([[8, 7, 2, 3],
       [1, 5, 3, 6],
       [9, 4, 3, 7],
       [5, 2, 6, 1]])
```

Comment: numpy is  not an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` module to do it. It has the property to transpose the array. Check the below code:

```
import numpy as np
m = [[5,9,1,8],
    [2,4,5,7],
    [6,3,3,2],
    [1,7,6,3]]
arr = np.array(m).transpose()
new_list = []
for i in range(arr.shape[0]-1,-1,-1):
    new_list.append(list(arr[i]))

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[8, 7, 2, 3], [1, 5, 3, 6], [9, 4, 3, 7], [5, 2, 6, 1]]
```

Comment: Hey thank you, i get this. i am trying to figure out how i can indent it so it can look like m originally

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the list clockwise:

```
list(map(list, zip(*m[::-1])))
```

Else, for anti-clockwise:

```
list(map(list, zip(*m)))[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

use the reverse keyword

```
result = [[5, 2, 6, 1], [9, 4, 3, 7], [1, 5, 3, 6], [8, 7, 2, 3]]
result.reverse()
print(result)
```

output:

```
[[8, 7, 2, 3], [1, 5, 3, 6], [9, 4, 3, 7], [5, 2, 6, 1]]
```