# How to remove outer brackets when printing 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, printing

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import matrix

MM = matrix([[1.00,0,0],[0,1.50,0],[0,0,2.00]])
M = np.array(MM)
print("matrix M: \n", M)
```

which output looks like this:

```
matrix M: 
 [[1.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  1.5 0. ]
 [0.  0.  2. ]]
```

This is very aesthetic, but I want it to look more organized. Something like this hopefully:

```
[1.  0.   0.]
[0.  1.5  0.]
[0.  0.   2.]
```

Comment: You can create a custom 'to_string()' method. Regretfully, python print in this fashion the n-dimensional array.....

Comment: You can fix the alignment of the first line of `M` in the output with `print("matrix M: \n", M, sep='')`.  But you'll still have the outer square brackets.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser right, but it won't remove the double square brackets like OP apparently wants

Comment: After having read the answers I'm now not sure if I should've edited the title. What is your exact question? How to remove the brackets? How to align the values? How to remove the space before the matrix?

Comment: I'd suggest a test case that involves a wider range of values.  For example a '12.3' in one row could mess up the row-by-row formatting.  A big plus for the default matrix format is that it keeps columns aligned.  Getting rid of the outer set of [] might not be worth the effort.  A `np.matrix` is always 2d, but other numpy arrays may be 1d or 3d.

Answer (score 2):

If you print `M` on its own it actually looks as you expect.

The reason why the first line gets messed up is because `print` inserts a space between its arguments by default. You can suppress that by providing `sep=''`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print for reference.

Or better yet, omit `\n` from the first print argument and use `sep='\n'` instead:

```
>>> print("matrix M:", M, sep='\n')
matrix M: 
[[1.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  1.5 0. ]
 [0.  0.  2. ]]
```

Comment: Looks like OP does not want the the double square brackets at all

Comment: thank you! the double square brackets don't matter, it looks nice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close:

```
'\n'.join('[{}]'.format(' '.join(str(n) for n in row)) for row in M)
```

Outputs

```
[1.0 0.0 0.0]
[0.0 1.5 0.0]
[0.0 0.0 2.0]
```

This removes the indentation and the double square brackets.

However, with very large matrices this might be slow due to the nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

**The exact desired output is this:**

```
print('\n'.join('[{}]'.format('. '.join(str(float(n)) for n in row)) for row in M))

[1.0. 0.0. 0.0]
[0.0. 1.5. 0.0]
[0.0. 0.0. 2.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As describes here [Pretty print 2D Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214809/pretty-print-2d-python-list/36538580)
, a very nice option is the following:

```
s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in M]
lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
print('\n'.join(table))

1.0     0.0     0.0
0.0     1.5     0.0
0.0     0.0     2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much extra code/complexity you want for a solution here, you can do a few things.  You can use a custom function in the `print` statement if you really want fine-grained control over the output (using code offered up in some of the other proposed solutions), but a less cumbersome approach that still gives you a decent amount of flexibility is to use the [array2string](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) function already included in Numpy.

A few examples using your scenario:

- Without any arguments:

```
>>> print(np.array2string(a=M))
[[1.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  1.5 0. ]
 [0.  0.  2. ]]
```

- Using the `separator` argument to add a bit of padding around elements:

```
>>> print(np.array2string(a=M, separator='   '))
[[1.    0.    0. ]
 [0.    1.5   0. ]
 [0.    0.    2. ]]
```

- If the leading and trailing brackets are bothersome, you can go a bit further with the `print` statement (`array2string` doesn't give you a way to change this) itself, doing a bit of manipulation to account for the character spacing with the brackets being removed:

```
>>> print(' ' + np.array2string(a=M, separator='   ')[1:-1])
 [1.    0.    0. ]
 [0.    1.5   0. ]
 [0.    0.    2. ]
```

Note that the last scenario still leaves a space at the beginning of each line.  You could use regexes to clean this up.

I realize that this may not be *exactly* what you are looking for in terms of output, but I thought I might offer up a lighter weight alternative that gets you mostly there.