# How do i print a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to print words in a text file   here's my code: 
shivas_file = open ("words.txt")

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989334/create-nice-column-output-in-python

Comment: Try `print x[0],'\t',x[1],'\t',x[2]` if you're using Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make tab delimited columns

```
for line in shivas_file:
    print('\t'.join(line.split(",")))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
x[0]+'\t'+x[1]+'\t'+x[2]
```

If you don't want tab try this

```
print (x[0]+x[1]+x[2])
```

Comment: @corykarmer answer is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) method.

```
print '{:<15} {:<15} {:<15}'.format(x[0],x[1]x[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using syntax of python3 in python2.
In python3, print is a function, but in python2 - its just a statement.
If you want python2, use

```
print x[0],'\t',x[1],'\t',x[2]
```

instead of

```
print(x[0],'\t',x[1],'\t',x[2])
```

Comment: `print('\t'.join(x))` would work in both Python 2 & 3.

Comment: yes, but I wanted to highlight a possible fact of wrong interpreter choice. It may lead to some troubles later.

Answer (score 0):

For better alignment, try this (for Python 3, please change the print call):

```
shivas_file = ['abc,    defggggggggg, kjdfksjdlkfjslkf'
, 'abcfdsfsdfskdjf,    gggg, kjdfksjdlkfjslkf'
, 'abc,    defggggg, kjdfksjdlkfjslkf']
for line in shivas_file:
    x = line.split(",")
    s = '%-20s %-20s %-20s' % tuple(x)
    print s
```

output:

```
abc                      defggggggggg      kjdfksjdlkfjslkf
abcfdsfsdfskdjf          gggg              kjdfksjdlkfjslkf
abc                      defggggg          kjdfksjdlkfjslkf
```