# Printing numbers in column

Tags: python, printing, numbers

I want to print numbers in appropriate way in Python:

```
0  6 12
1  7 13
2  8 14
3  9 15
4 10 16
```

I want to do it in function e.g. `num_print(x, y, step)`
where:

```
x - number of columns
y - number of rows
step - diff between numbers in row
```

I did something like this, but this is not what I want, because **when I call function the value of columns is not appropriate (13 should be 3)**:

```
def num_print(vert, hori, step):
    for y in range(vert):
        for x in range(y, y + hori, step):
            print(x, end = ' ')
        print('')
num_print(5, 13, 6)
```

Can someone show me maybe better way how to do this? and indentation of numbers like in example is welcome ;)

Comment: This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989334/create-nice-column-output-in-python

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't fix my all problems, which I show in my post.