# Print Python output into two columns

Tags: python

Trying to replicate a basic column command in a Python program to print a list of States to the user via the command line:

```
us_states_list_with_population = [   
("Alabama" , "AL" , 4903185),
("Montana" , "MT" , 1068778),
("Alaska" , "AK" , 731545),
...

]

for state_name , state_abbreviation , num_counties in us_states_list_with_population: 
    print(state_name + " (" + state_abbreviation + ")")
```

Is there an easy way to split the output into two or three columns to make this shorter and more readable?

Desired output would be something like:

```
Alabama (AL)        Alaska (AK)
Montana (MT)        California (CA)
...
```

Versus:

```
Alabama (AL)
Alaska (AK)
Montana (MT)
California (CA)
...
```

Comment: What is so *not* easy about the method you posted?  It's straightforward and easy to read.  The next step would be to convert your list to a Pandas data frame and dump formatted output from there, but this method has more overhead.

Comment: Are you looking for merely output formatting?  If so, that's an easy browser search for the documentation.

Comment: Yes, this would be in accordance with output formatting to generate two separate columns.

Comment: Pandas handles tabular data much better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create nice column output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989334/create-nice-column-output-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired OUTPUT you can try this.

```
us_states_list_with_population = [   
("Alabama" , "AL" , 4903185),
("Montana" , "MT" , 1068778),
("Alaska" , "AK" , 731545),
]

row = []
num_of_columns = 2
for state_name , state_abbreviation , num_counties in us_states_list_with_population:
    row.append(f'{state_name} ({state_abbreviation})')
    if len(row) == num_of_columns:
        print(("\t").join(row))
        row.clear()
print(("\t").join(row)) # print last row if there is a remainder
```

Or if you want to learn more prettier tabulates check @cricket_007 comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate them by tabs, rather than spaces.

```
for state_name , state_abbreviation , num_counties in us_states_list_with_population: 
    print(state_name + "\t(" + state_abbreviation + ")")
```

The `\t` there will get translated into a tab when printed.