# How to get a for loop outputs in a straight vertical line

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm a student who is recently been studying the basics of **Python**. So I faced this problem while doing one of my projects. If someone could explain a solution that is not too complex for my stage I would be grateful.

```
students = ['Sam', 'Ben', 'John', 'Michael']
marks = [27, 68, 34, 21]
print('Student Name - Mark')
for n in range(0, len(marks)):
    print(students[n], marks[n])
```

gives the result

```
Student Name - Mark
Sam 27
Ben 68
John 34
Michael 21
```

To make it look nicer, I need to take this second list of members which are the **marks** in a straight vertical line.
the expected result is:

```
Student Name - Mark
Sam            27
Ben            68
John           34
Michael        21
```

P.S. I was unable to find an answer through google.

Comment: Some great answers here: [Create nice column output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989334/create-nice-column-output-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can f-string to specify fixed length.

```py
students = ['Sam', 'Ben', 'John', 'Michael']
marks = [27, 68, 34, 21]

print('Student Name - Mark')
for student, mark in zip(students, marks):
    print(f"{student:14} {mark}")
```

Output:

```
Student Name - Mark
Sam            27
Ben            68
John           34
Michael        21
```

Also note the use of `zip`; `for ... in range(len(...))` is usually thought to be un-pythonic.

Comment: I actually didn't know about zip or the f string. I used the last row print(f"{student:{max(len(x) for x in students)}} {mark}") so I don't need guess how long it need to be when it comes to long values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SachithJayalath Yes, that's a better approach, to avoid hard-coded values.