# How to format the output with methods?

Tags: python

I have a combination of methods. And I try to fromat them correct.

So I have this functions:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import itertools
import locale
import operator
import re


i50 ="[' \n\na)\n\n \n\nFactuur\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\nFactuur nr. : 71201\n\nrut ard wegetables\n\x0c']"

fruit_words = ['Appels', 'Ananas', 'Peen Waspeen',
               'Tomaten Cherry', 'Sinaasappels',
               'Watermeloenen', 'Rettich', 'Peren', 'Peen', 'Mandarijnen', 'Meloenen', 'Grapefruit']

def total_amount_fruit_regex(format_=re.escape):
    return r"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*~?=?\s*(" + '|'.join(
        format_(word) for word in fruit_words) + ')'

def total_fruit_per_sort():
    number_found = re.findall(total_amount_fruit_regex(), verdi50)

    fruit_dict = {}
    for n, f in number_found:
        fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + int(n)
        result = '\n'.join(f'{key}: {val}' for key, val in fruit_dict.items())   
    return result


def fruit_list(format_=re.escape):
        return "|".join(format_(word) for word in fruit_words)


def findallfruit(regex):
    return re.findall(regex, verdi50)


def verdi_total_number_fruit_regex():
    return rf"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*\W+(?:{fruit_list()})"


def show_extracted_data_from_file():
    regexes = [     
       verdi_total_number_fruit_regex(),       
    ] 
    matches = [findallfruit(regex) for regex in regexes]    
    return "\n".join(" \t ".join(items) for items in zip(*matches)) + "\t" + total_fruit_per_sort()
    

print(show_extracted_data_from_file())
```

this give as output:

```
16
360
6
75
9
688
22
80
160
320
6
75
9
688
22
80
160
320
160
61      Watermeloenen: 466
Appels: 688
Sinaasappels: 803
```

But I want them like this:

```
16       Watermeloenen: 466
360      Appels: 688
6        Sinaasappels: 803
75
9
688
22
80
160
320
6
75
9
688
22
80
160
320
160
61
```

So that they are next to each other. But how to do this?

Comment: There are a few problems in the code and I cannot reproduce it correctly. Can you please fix it? Thank you.

Comment: `verdi50` by itself on a line doesn't do anythinng.

Comment: You still have the useless `verdi50` line at the beginning of `show_extracted_data_from_file()`. What is that for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're concatenating `total_fruit_per_sort()` at the end of the join. You need to concatenate it to the first 3 items being joined.

You can split it into lines, then use `itertools.zip_longest()` to loop over this in parallel with the generator.

```
def show_extracted_data_from_file():
    regexes = [
       verdi_total_number_fruit_regex(),
    ]
    matches = [findallfruit(regex) for regex in regexes]
    fruit_list = total_fruit_per_sort().split("\n")
    return "\n".join(" \t ".join(items) for items in zip_longest(*matches, fruit_list, fillvalue=''))
```

Comment: Nice answer :)
For printing it in a pretty way you can use many of the nice python tools available, look at this thread for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989334/create-nice-column-output-in-python

I used `tabulate` to test your code, and it worked well.
Note you'll need to keep the data in it's double-list stratuce and not as string and then print it, so:

```
res = zip_longest(*matches, fruit_list, fillvalue='')
print(tabulate(res, headers=["first column name", "second column name"]))
```

Comment: @imaayanl. Ah, yes, Because I want to have it more tighter. Yes, indeed. Becasue the cost output is still not straight. Do you have an example with tabulate? for this specific case? Because yes, I also want to have headers above the data columns